# Simple build system with support for filename spaces?

Tags: build, build-system

I am having trouble finding a build system for my Madoko Markdown Notes. These notes are simply a directory of files which get processed with `madoko mynote.mdk` to produce `out/mynote.html`. GNU Make was working great for this purpose until I created a note with a space in its filename. It's clear that GNU Make just cannot handle this. Which is disappointing because I don't know any other systems like GNU Make.

What other build systems could I try that could handle this task?

Answer (score 0):

Over time, different programming languages or ecosystems usually produce their own build tool. These are therefore usually more coupled to the respective context they are expected to be used in. Though `make` is already an older build tool, it is still much used for it does not make too much assumptions on what you are trying to build. However it has its limits, as you discovered yourself.

Personally, I've refrained myself to not use spaces in filenames anymore, and still use Madoko with `make`. However, if this isn't convenient to you, your options are tool that intrinsically will bring more contextual assumptions with them. For example, with the Gradle tool of the Java world it would generally be easy to accomplish your requirement, but you'll have to express it with Groovy syntax and each run of your task will power up a JVM. Another example is Rake, which requires you to introduce a Ruby ecosystem. However, I would recommend you to give this a try, for it is rather easy but still powerful, and definitely more lightweight that a JVM approach. Another more heterogenous approach could be Cmake, but lacking any experience, I can't say anything about ups or downs.

- https://github.com/ruby/rake
- https://gradle.org
- https://cmake.org

Comment: Its nice to hear from someone who also uses Madoko. Thank you for the suggestions, there are so many domain specific build tools that I needed some. In the mean time I created a shell script that is doing what I need for now based upon the [ "$source" -nt "$target" ] test which checks if a source file is newer than the output. I'll post the code as an alternative solution soon.

Comment: P.S. I have trouble accepting that space should be excluded from filenames.

Answer (score 0):

A rather simple solution that is working for me so far is a simple shell script based on the `["$source" -nt "$target"]` shell test as shown below. I'm interested in adding a `-watch` option using `inotifywait` to compile each file as it's modified. Running the following script without arguments compiles all "stale" `.mdk` files in the working directory.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

TOBUILD=()
while [[ $# -gt 0 ]]; do
  case $1 in
    clean|-clean|-c) # Clean output directory
    CLEAN=true
    shift
    ;;
    -f|--force) # Force rebuild all files
    FORCE=true
    shift
    ;;
    *) # Force rebuild these files
    TOBUILD+=("$1")
    shift
    ;;
  esac
done

if [ "$CLEAN" = true ]; then
  rm -rf out
  exit
fi

if [ ${#TOBUILD[@]} -gt 0 ]; then
  FORCE=true
else
  for source in *.mdk; do
    TOBUILD+=("$source")
  done
fi
```